# Affecting returned PHP query result to HTML form input field

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Contents of main file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test JSON</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin : 100px;
        }
        h1 {
            text-align: center;

        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >

        $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#btn").click(getNewVal);

        });

        function getNewVal(){
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var queryString = "getVal.php?str=" + "Blah";
            xhr.open("GET", queryString, true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    //alert(document.getElementById("txtField").value);
                    var JSONObj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    alert(JSONObj.item);
                    document.getElementById("txtField").value = JSONObj.item;

                }
            }


            xhr.send(null); 
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test JSON</h1>
    <hr />

    <form id="testForm" method="GET" action="">
        <label>Custom Value: </label>
        <input type="text" value="La valeur a changer" id="txtField">
        <input type="submit" value="Bouton pour changer la valeur" id="btn">
    </form>

</body>
```

Contents of ajax call file

```
<?php

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Problème avec la connection : " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else{
    if(isset($_GET['str'])) {
        $val = $_GET['str'];
        $post_data = array('item' => $_GET['str']);
        echo json_encode($post_data);
    }
    else{
        echo "error";
    }

}
?>
```

I want to return the result of the query and affect it to an html text input field in another php file. After making the changes for JSON everything works, except the `document.getElementById("txtField").value = JSONObj.item;` in the onreadystatechange. What am i missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of your current `echo` line, simply echo the `$result` of the query in JSON or some other basic format. In your JS code, parse the response and use it to change your `<input>`.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I've edited my last post to reflect the current problem, if you have another moment to take a look I'd appreciate it a lot. Thanks!

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. I assume the `alert()` is happening and displaying the returned data? Did you check the console for errors? Here's a working fiddle with a dummy request: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/mqqtbepu/ (I changed the handler to handle form submission and return false)